# Using jQuery to get jsonp data returns invalid label error

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I have been using jquery ajax method to get the json data. I have used both jQuery.getJSON 
and jquery.ajax methods but I keep getting the same error in my console. **Invalid label meta** I just want to display the some of the json data inside a div , is there something 
wrong with the json file the java script works fine with other json files. I dont know how to parse this particular json file.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = text/javascript>         
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.yipit.com/v1/deals/?key=TMBYhd3hkzfCntMb&limit=20&division=boston', 
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
      }
    });

    return;
});

        </script>
```

I just tried to parse the data but I am not able to see the result. 
In the console I get a error saying **field.deals.url** not defined ?
I am also able to see jQuery16209054896509423064_1311611178838({ on top of the
meta how can I parse this file ?

```
<script type = text/javascript>


    $(document).ready(function(){
         $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.yipit.com/v1/deals/?key=TMBYhd3hkzfCntMb&limit=20&division=boston&callback=?', 
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data){
                        $.each(data.response, function(i, field){
                        $('#display').append('<p>url : ' + field.deals.url+ '</p>');
                                    if ( i == 3 ) return false;
                });
          }
        });

        return;
    });

            </script>
```

Comment: Nevermind, looks like a good API, but I don't see how (if you're disallowing jsonp) you're going to get data back x-domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `jsonp: false,` you have to use JSONP in this cross domain case.

This will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.yipit.com/v1/deals/?key=TMBYhd3hkzfCntMb&limit=20&division=boston', 
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Working example: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XsEGE/1/)

EDIT:

deals is your iterator not response

```
success: function(data){
    $.each(data.response.deals, function(i, field){
        $('#display').append('<p>url : ' + field.url+ '</p>');
             if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
```

Comment: I deleted jsonp: false but when I see the response in my console jQuery16209054896509423064_1311611178838 { gets appended to my json file before the meta , which i assume is the jquery callback value I am not sure, and because of this I am not able to travel down the hierarchy and display my desired data.

Comment: jQuery16209054896509423064_1311611178838 {( some thing like this gets appended to the top how can I parse this

Comment: That's the callback function. If you are doing your work in the `success` function hook, you should never have to deal with that.

Comment: Joey I edited my question , So the hierarchy is response->deals->url which is what I am trying to display , is my success function right? thanks a lot for replying joey